# How can I integrate Bootstrap with Python programming language and the Django framework?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

I would like to know what is the exact process to follow when building a web application using bootstrap python and django. Is bootstrap simply a template of HTML and CSS files which should be manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple process actually!

1. Download the bootstrap file here (the first option)-
   http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download
2. Place the folder into your main app's static folder. You can then start to use classes from bootstrap in your HTML.
3. Make sure your static assets are set correctly so Django knows where to find the bootstrap components. Here's a detailed tutorial if you need more help. http://www.effectivedjango.com/tutorial/static.html

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap are mainly CSS and Javascript files that you can use from your web application html. You can use whatever backend you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should use [django-bootstrap3](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3). This package is easy to use and has an active development support. For detailed docs, please read [this](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Also you can look at [django-twitter-bootstrap](https://github.com/estebistec/django-twitter-bootstrap) to try out another option.